# Sublime text 3: How can I insert wrapping HTML elements like Dreamweaver

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

Everytime I'm putting HTML tags I need to wrap into a new element. I remember you can do this on Dreamweaver just inserting an element when you select something. Is there a way to do this with sublime text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the text you want to wrap, and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>. It will initially be wrapped in `<p>` tags, but you can just type the tag you want and the tags will automatically change.

[image]